# Cron syntax - plus/minus sign

Tags: linux, unix, cron

What do plus and minus signs at the start of lines mean in cron syntax?

```
+ 0 9 * * * /usr/bin/curl -k http://www.example.com/cron/deactivate_users
- 10 8 * * * /usr/bin/curl -k http://example.com/cron/delete_users
```

Comment: I have never seen any `-` or `+` in a crontab syntax. Is it working? I tested in my machine and it does not accept the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no + or - */2 is there I think you have seen the above syntax somewhere where + means to add the line to curl and call deactivate_users and remove i.e - to remove delete_users or in short words to replace delete_users cronjob with the new cronjob of deactivate_users.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Answer (score 4):

As of the minus sign:

If a line inside a crontab starts with a '-' this will prevent cron from writing to the syslog about the execution of the command.

See manpage (5) of crontab.

Answer (score 2):

It (i.e. your lines starting with `+` or `-`) probably is the output of some [GNU diff](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) (or some other `diff`), so it is a *[patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28computing%29)* file.

You may apply that patch with the [patch](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/patch/) command. Try perhaps `patch < your.diff`(or else `patch -p0 < your.diff`)  where `your.diff` contains such lines starting with `+` or `-` (and also a few previous ones).